# Which unicode block is needed to display certain latin-based language?

Tags: flash, unicode, multilingual

**Background** 
In Flash you have the option to embed only certain unicode blocks of selected font. Those characters will then be available in your project.

**Question**
Which unicode block is needed to display certain latin-based language? It's obvious in cases like *Greek* or *Hebrew* but what latin extension do I need for German, Danish or Czech language?

**I know I should be able to google it but I simply can not find the answer.**

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746270/unicode-range-mapping-between-languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All *letters* needed for German and Danish are in the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_Controls_and_Basic_Latin) and [C1 Controls and Latin-1 Supplement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C1_Controls_and_Latin-1_Supplement) blocks. (See [Wikipedia's list of languages supported by those blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=ISO/IEC_8859-1&oldid=444304508#Languages_with_complete_coverage).)

For Czech/Slovak, you also need [Latin Extended-A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_Extended-A).

You should also include General Punctuation, as well as any other symbols you may use (e.g. Arrows).

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_characters_in_Unicode.

Comment: thanks, but what I need is to pair that table with world languages.