# Unicode range mapping between languages

Tags: unicode

there is 7707 languages listed in this link http://www.sil.org/iso639-3/download.asp and [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639:a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639%3aa).

And also Unicode support the writing system of the languages, but i want to know mapping beetween the languages and unicode range.

Unicode range is listed in this link http://www.unicode.org/roadmaps/bmp/

Example one of unicode range : "start"=> "0x0900", "end"=> "0x097F", "block_name"=> "Devanagari" (what language use this range of unicode ?)

there is any documentation ? I need full languages mapping that are supported in unicode range.

Comment: Scripts to languages is not a 1-to-1 mapping. Where would you map `'a'` to? At best you can build a many-to-many mapping of scripts to languages and look up matching sets. Something like [Onmiglot](http://www.omniglot.com/writing/langalph.htm) might be a useful resource.

Comment: yes, many to many mapping. thanks for the link, very helpful, there is any completed list ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any standardized list or resource that maps scripts to languages. That said, I haven't pondered this particular question very hard, so it might well exist, but I wonder if this is of any use. There isn't really a general textual way to discover the language of a text, and most real-world texts probably don't even have a well-defined single language (just look at any German advert). Discovering the script from the codepoint is fine; anything beyond that is the responsibility of a higher-level protocol, like HTML's `lang` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at ICU4C locale (http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/uloc_8h.html)

You can get all the locales (with uloc_getAvailable), then for each locale call uloc_addLikelySubtags, and then uloc_getScript on the result.

This is going to give you the most likely script used by a language. But there are languages that use more than one script. Some of them are captured by ICU, but some are not.